# 'ImageDataGenerator' object has no attribute 'class_indices'

Tags: keras

Was the attribute removed in the version 1.4? In the documentation it is still reffered: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator

Comment: Remember that this is attribute of `flow_from_directory` object - not `ImageDataGenerator`.

Comment: Thank you. I think, I tried it also, will check this evening. Weanwhile I've solved my problem by using the correct order of classes. As I found out, flow_from_directory orders the classes in alphabetical order.

Comment: I got this problem in a kaggle kernel. How did you fix this?